# How do I express $a+ab+a^2b+a^2b^2+a^3b^2+a^3b^3+a^4b^3+....$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

How do I express the following infinite sum?

$$a+ab+a^2b+a^2b^2+a^3b^2+a^3b^3+a^4b^3+....$$

I can't quite figure this out. I'm only looking for hints, or maybe the full expression, nothing fancy required!

Comment: isn't it $a+(a+1)ab+(a+1)a^2b^2 \cdots$ ?

Comment: Just do it.  Each term is of the form $a^{k+1}b^k$ so it would be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^{k+1}b^k$.

Comment: @fleablood:  no, we have $a^kb^k$ as well in there.

Comment: Oh.  That explains what everyone else was seeing.  But is $\sum(a^{k+1}b^k + a^kb^k) = (a+1)\sum (ab)^k$ which if it converges is $\frac {a+1}{1-ab}$.  (assuming $|ab| < 1$.)

Comment: Now *this* is a well posed question! Good job

Answer (score 3):

$$a+\sum_{n\ge 1}(ab)^n(1+a)$$
is one of the possible formulæ. Another would be
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}a^{n+1}b^n(1+b).$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^nb^{n-1} +a^nb^n$$

That's what I first thought when I saw the problem

Answer (score 1):

$1+a+ab+a^2b+...=

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a^{k+1}b^k+a^kb^k) = (a+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(ab)^k$.

This sum only converges if $|ab| < 1$ in which case it converges to $\frac {a+1}{1- ab}$.

But your sum is $1$ less.  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a^{k+1}b^k+a^kb^k) = (a+1)(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(ab)^k)-1$.

Which converges to $\frac {a+ab}{1-ab} $.

Answer (score 0):

$$a+ab+a^2b+a^2b^2+a^3b^2+a^3b^3+a^4b^3+.... =\sum _{k=1}^\infty a^k(b^{k-1}+b^k)$$